# c++ .cpp file not found error page during breakpoint debugging

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

My code compiles and runs without any error messages, however I commented out a line (and it still runs with no errors) but the code executed as if the line was not commented out.
I set a breakpoint and tried to step into the function where the problem seemed to be, but when I tried to step in I was instead sent to this screen

[image: button.cpp not found]

If I press the "Browse and find button.cpp", then I am immediately shown this message

[image: the source file is different from when the module was built]

If I press "yes" then it shows me the correct file, with the line commented out, but then proceeds to execute the commented out line as if it was not commented out at all.

Pressing "no" closes the box, however selecting the correct .cpp file just opens it up again.

I've made sure the file is saved, and restarted visual studio, and the problem persists.

Here is the surrounding code:

### The function that brings me to this page

```
vector<GameObject*> gameObjects;
for each (auto object in gameObjects)
{
    object->Render();
}
```

`Button` is a templated class and inherits from `PhysicsObject` which inherits from `GameObject`
`Render()` is a virtual method of `object` and `PhysicsObject`

### The code that should not be executed but is

```
template<class T>
void Button<T>::Render()
{
//PhysicsObject::Render();
}
```

I've never seen any error like this before and it only seems to tell me it's a problem when I step through the code with a breakpoint.
I have no idea how to even search for this kind of error message and I have no idea what it means or what caused it.
I did not edit my code during execution and I didn't change anything about the structure of my project, this was working before.

Comment: Stupid question but we never know : did you recompile the project ?

Comment: Try cleaning the solution `Build->Clean the solution`

Comment: Oh yes ! If you are writing you code in .h it may be not took into account !
Try to rebuild the whole solution as @AlexLarionov suggested

Comment: @AlexLarionov wow I had no idea it would be that simple, cleaning the project and rebuilding fixed it completely. Any idea what causes something like this?

Comment: For one reason or another (like moving the project around) the debugger information files thought Button.cpp was somewhere else. Stale info that's been cached can follow you around for a while.